# Kinetic Energy of a rod with two ends moving

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rigid-body-dynamics

I've seen in bibliography that the kinetic energy of a uniform rod of mass $m$, whose ends are moving perpendicular to the length of the rod and in the same direction with velocities $u$ and $v$ is

$$T=\frac{m}{6}\left(u^2+v^2+uv\right).$$

I do not know how to prove it, any ideas?

Comment: How can the two ends move perpendicular to the rod with different velocities?

Comment: @sammygerbil See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First lets show that why the situation you've described is even possible ("too long for a comment" answer to @sammygerbil comment). Consider rotation at $\omega$ of the rod around an axis where one end is at $r=L_{1}$ and the other is at $r=L_{2}$.  The velocities of the ends are $v_{1}=\omega L_{1}$ and $v_{2}=\omega L_{2}$ respectively. Taking into account the length of the rod $L=L_{2}-L_{1}$, you get

$$\begin{cases}v_{1}=\omega \left(L_{2}-L\right)\\v_{2}=\omega L_{2}\end{cases}$$

You can solve these equations for $\omega$ and $L_{2}$

$$\begin{cases}L_{2}=\frac{L}{1-\frac{v_{1}}{v_{2}}}\\\omega=\frac{v_{2}-v_{1}}{L}\end{cases}$$

so the solution exists as long as $v_{2}>v_{1}$. The cases $v_{2}=v_{1}$ is degenerate and also possible. This proves the solution always exists because of symmetry between the edges.

Now lets solve your problem. The only parameters in this problem are the mass $m$, the length of the rod $L$ and the velocities $u,v$. Therefore, by means of dimensional analysis the energy must be given as an expression of the form

$$T=m\left(au^{2}+av^{2}+buv\right)$$

where $a$ and $b$ are dimensionless constants, and the symmetry between $u$ and $v$ has been used. We left with the job of finding some easy edge cases. Indeed

$$T\left(u=v\right)=\frac{1}{2}mv^{2}\Longrightarrow 4a+2b=1$$

$$T\left(u=0\right)=\frac{1}{2}I\omega^{2}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{mL^{2}}{3}\frac{v^{2}}{L^{2}}=\frac{1}{6}mv^{2}\Longrightarrow a=\frac{1}{6}$$

and you are left with

$$T=\frac{1}{6}m\left(u^{2}+v^{2}+uv\right)$$

as needed.